# Should I have to nest Ember.run & andThen functions when doing testing?

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I'm writing tests in Ember with Qunit and I find my code looking like:

```
Ember.run(function(){ ... });

andThen(function(){ 
  Ember.run( ... )
  andThen(function(){
    ...
  });
});
```

I have some tests that are nested beyond 3-4 times. Is nesting Ember.run & andThen functions necessary or bad practice?

Comment: did you find out an answer?

Comment: I tested it and tried to remove them but it broke my tests. I haven't found a better way. So, until I find a better way, yes it is necessary.